# Metodo compareTo en java

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un trabajo para clase y tengo que ordenar un `arraylist` por fecha, he implementado la clase comparable pero la verdad que no se como crear el compare to.

La clase parte de trabajo tiene: Nombre del cliente, dirección del cliente, fecha del parte, nombre del trabajador que lo va a realizar, estado ((P)endiente/(R)ealizado), fecha prevista de reparación, tiempo empleado en minutos, descripción del arreglo
concretamente me pide Ordenar los partes de trabajo por la fecha del parte de forma ascendente.
 Os dejo mi código:

```
 public class ParteDeTrabajo {

    private String nombreCliente;
    private LocalDate fechaParte;
    private String nombreTrabajador;
    private char estado;
    private LocalDate fechaReparacion;
    private double tiempoReparacion;
    private String descripcionArreglo;
    private ArrayList<Material> materiales;

    public String getNombreCliente() {
        return nombreCliente;
    }

    public void setNombreCliente(String nombreCliente) {
        this.nombreCliente = nombreCliente;
    }

    public LocalDate getFechaParte() {
        return fechaParte;
    }

    public void setFechaParte(LocalDate fechaParte) {
        this.fechaParte = fechaParte;
    }

    public String getNombreTrabajador() {
        return nombreTrabajador;
    }

    public void setNombreTrabajador(String nombreTrabajador) {
        this.nombreTrabajador = nombreTrabajador;
    }

    public char getEstado() {
        return estado;
    }

    public void setEstado(char estado) {
        if (this.estado == 'p' || this.estado == 'R') {
            this.estado = estado;
        }
    }

    public LocalDate getFechaReparacion() {
        return fechaReparacion;
    }

    public void setFechaReparacion(LocalDate fechaReparacion) {
        this.fechaReparacion = fechaReparacion;
    }

    public double getTiempoReparacion() {
        return tiempoReparacion;
    }

    public void setTiempoReparacion(double tiempoReparacion) {
        if (this.tiempoReparacion >= 0) {
            this.tiempoReparacion = tiempoReparacion;
        }
    }

    public String getDescripcionArreglo() {
        return descripcionArreglo;
    }

    public void setDescripcionArreglo(String descripcionArreglo) {
        this.descripcionArreglo = descripcionArreglo;
    }

    public ArrayList<Material> getMateriales() {
        return materiales;
    }

    public void setMateriales(ArrayList<Material> materiales) {
        this.materiales = materiales;
    }

    public ParteDeTrabajo(String nombreCliente, LocalDate fechaParte, String nombreTrabajador, char estado, LocalDate fechaReparacion, double tiempoReparacion, String descripcionArreglo, ArrayList<Material> materiales) {
        this.nombreCliente = nombreCliente;
        this.fechaParte = fechaParte;
        this.nombreTrabajador = nombreTrabajador;
        setEstado(estado);
        this.fechaReparacion = fechaReparacion;
        setTiempoReparacion(tiempoReparacion);
        this.descripcionArreglo = descripcionArreglo;
        this.materiales = materiales;
    }

    public ParteDeTrabajo() {
        this.nombreCliente = "";
        this.fechaParte = null;
        this.nombreTrabajador = "";
        this.estado = 'p';
        this.fechaReparacion = null;
        this.tiempoReparacion = 0;
        this.descripcionArreglo = "";
        this.materiales = new ArrayList<Material>();
    }

    public String aniadirMateriales(Material a) {
        materiales.add(a);
        return "material introducidos";
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String str = "";
        str += "Parte de trabajo" + "\n";
        str += "fecha del parte: " + fechaParte + "\n  nombre del cliente: " + nombreCliente + "\n  Atendido por: " + nombreTrabajador
                + "\n  estado del parter: " + estado + "\n fecha de reparacion: " + fechaReparacion + "\n se ha tardado: " + tiempoReparacion
                + "minutos \n ";
        for (Material m : materiales) {
            str += m.toString();
        }

        return str;
    }

}
```

Comment: ¿Dónde está la fecha que vas a usar para ordenar? En el código que compartes no es claro

Comment: ahora si perdón no me lo había cogido todo el texto no se porque. la fecha esta en la clase Parte de trabajo que en el 2º párrafo pone la descripción

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un método compareTo, puede devolverte tres valores:
1  si  a > b , -1 si  a < b ,0 si   a = b

```
    public int compareTo(ParteDeTrabajo pdt) {
     // caso a = b
     int resultadoComparacion = 0;
     // Caso a > b
     if (this.fechaReparacion.isAfter(pdt.fechaReparacion)) {
        resultadoComparacion = 1;
    }
     // Caso a < b
     if (this.fechaReparacion.isBefore(pdt.fechaReparacion)) {
        resultadoComparacion = -1;
    }

     return resultadoComparacion;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

La interfaz Comparable sirve, como su nombre indica, para hacer que los objetos de una clase sean comparables entre sí. Por tanto, son los elementos que guardas en las colecciones que quieres ordenar los que tienen que cumplirla.

Tendrías que hacer algo como:

```
class ParteDeTrabajo implements Comparable<ParteDeTrabajo> {

    // resto de código

    public int compareTo(ParteDeTrabajo pdt) {
        if (pdt == null) {
            return 1; //podemos asumir que this es mayor que null
        }
        // asumo que la fecha es de tipo LocalDate, Date o similar, que ya cumplen 
        //la interfaz Comparable
        return this.fechaReparacion.compareTo(pdt.fechaReparacion);

    }

}
```

Y entonces no tienes más que ordenar tu lista:

```
this.pilaDePartes.sort();
```

Comment: Entonces el compareTo va en la clase partes de trabajo y no en la clase empresa?yo pense que iria donde esta el arraylist.voy a modificar entonces el codigo para que veas la clase Parte de trabajo

Comment: Te he actualizado levemente la respuesta, pero realmente es lo mismo: tienes que decir cómo ordenar tus objetos, devolviendo 1 cuando el objeto actual (this) va primero, 0 cuando los dos objetos son "igual de grandes" y -1 cuando el actual es menor y, por tanto, va segundo.